# Black and red wires

Tags: electrical

When replacing a light switch and fixture, I noticed there were only 2 wires...red/black connected to the switch. The new fixture has a black/white/ground. What is the proper way of connecting? The wires are the original red/black that went to the single pole switch. The fixture is a new light attaching to wall.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the situation?

Comment: What is the fixture?

Comment: The wires are the original red/black that went to the single pole switch. The fixture is a new light attaching to wall. @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: @DanielGriscom  The wires are the original red/black that went to the single pole switch. The fixture is a new light attaching to wall.

Comment: Good information, but it's best if you edit it into your original question; that way you're more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: What colors are the wires supplying voltage to the switch itself?  The wiring to the light fixture (assuming it's a 120VAC) can go either way, since it's the ground wire at the fixture which must be grounded to make the fixture itself safe.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like whoever wired it used the red as the switch leg coming back from the switch. The black was used as the hot feed to the switch.

There should also be a black/white cable from the panel to the light fixture box.

One of the boxes has to have the hot feed from the panel in it. Your post only talks about the cable from the switch to the light.

Look again for the other cable in one of the boxes.

Good luck!